# QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::ClassicMethod on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, bluetooth

When I run

```
deviceAgent=new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this);
deviceAgent->start(QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent::ClassicMethod);
```

I get the error:

> qt. bluetooth. android: Search not possible due to turned off Location service

If geolocation is enabled, everything works as it should.
How do I search ONLY CLASSIC bluetooth devices on android without enabling geolocation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on Qt 5.15, one workaround is back to Qt 5.13.2 were I know that is working.

Please upvote for they priorize: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90760